# JavaFx: how to add 3 tablecolumn under 2 tablecolumn

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn, tableheader

How to create a tableview in **JavaFx** like below?

```
---------------------------------------
| column one       |    column two    |
---------------------------------------
|  sub col1  |  sub col2  | sub col3  |
---------------------------------------
| data ....  |            |           |
 ...
 ...
 ...
```

I need something like tables in quickbook, there is no need to be relation in columns as main column or sub column. I only need to have a column header looking like table below.

[image: Quick book table]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm

Comment: please look at the section where it mentions "nested columns"

Comment: @StevenKimarro using nested columns we can add subcolumns under each column, but i need to add 3 subcolumn under 2 main column. the problem is that how can i position the middle column so the middle column appear under the first and second column (as shown above) ???

Comment: So how would sorting work? What would happen if you clicked "Column One" or "Column Two"? What would be the purpose of having those columns on the top anyway?

Comment: i don't need sorting, i only need to show the columns as shown above

Comment: IMO that's not a table layout at all. "sub col2" is a sub of column 1 or 2?

Comment: @UlukBiy i have updated my question to show what i exactly look for.
#Note: there is no need for main and sub column relation. i only need a column header looking like the image.